# Python subscribe to an event from separate file

Tags: python, events, io, raspberry-pi

OK, so I have pi_io.py file that monitors a input pin.  It fires every time the input state changes.  What I want to do is subscribe to this event in another class in another file.  So that the event will trigger in both classes.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

class Pi_Io:
    def __init__(self):        
        self.iscyclepressed = False
        self.cyclestart = 13
        # setup inputs
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(self.cyclestart, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
        GPIO.add_event_detect(self.cyclestart, GPIO.BOTH,
                            callback=self.CycleStart_In, bouncetime=50)

    def CycleStart_In(self, channel):
        if not GPIO.input(self.cyclestart):
            self.iscyclepressed = True
            print("Cycle Button Pressed")
        else:
            self.iscyclepressed = False
            print("Cycle Button Released")

Pi_Io()
while True:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another instance of your class in the separate file.

```
from pi_io import Pi_Io


instance = Pi_Io()
# rest of your code
```